# Store float as short int. Confusing results

Tags: c++, memory, time

I'm trying to save memory and time consumption storing 32bit float values in 16bit short variables. In order to do this I introduce conversion functions like this:

```
typedef short int StoreType;
StoreType FloatToShort( float x ) { return x/k; }
float ShortToFloat( StoreType x ) { return float(x)*k; }
```

Then I convert input data into StoreType array using first function. And each time I need some value I extract StoreType data and using second function get float value.

But when I want to estimate speed up optioned because of memory optimization and compare 2 cases:

1. Is described above - when StoreType == short int
2. Is exactly same, but StoreType == float ( first line is replaced by "typedef short int StoreType" ).

I see that in second case time is significantly Smaller (like 10% when measurement error is less than 1%) in spite of all my anticipations (calculations are same, cash usage is bigger with float).
Meanwhile my algorithm speed theoretically should not depend on intimidate result of calculation (i.e. precision). And the final result of the program practically doesn't change (less than 0.2% difference) with StoreType changes.
Also the program includes a number of computations with converted values, so type convertion time expected to be negligible in comparison to all computations.

How can be possible that the program is faster with floats?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question:  Are you asking why you get a precision problem when storing a 32-bit `float` as a 16-bit `int` and returning it to a 32-bit float?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you're trying to save computation time by storing a 32-bit number as a 16-bit number? You won't get a performance boost if you're converting every number every time you read/write it. You _might_ get some benefit if you store two values in the low/high bits of a 32 bit number. But you'll have to do all your numeric processing yourself.

Comment: The conversions back and forth take a significant amount of time.

Comment: Zac Howland, I did write that I DON"T have precision problem. I specify now more explicitly that I have time problem.

Comment: what is that k (float or int) ?

Comment: justjsm, yes, thank you, type conversion is needed, though I'm not sure that number of convert-function call is big enough, most computations is done after conversion.  And why you saying that it can help to pack 2 16bit numbers into one 32bit? In this case I will also need type conversion.

Comment: Dieter Lücking, float. Why?

Comment: @justjsm: He will lose performance, because conversion between ints and floats frequently ends up being bottleneck in floating point calculations.

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: There is a dirty trick one could play if you absolutely need a compact number, need the range of a float, but only need about 8 bits of precision:  Use Float.floatToRawIntBits to convert to a 32-bit int, then discard the low-order 16 bits.  (intBitsToFloat the other way.)  This is a native method call but should be "stackless" if the C compiler is smart enough and would be very fast.  Whether it's faster than normal float<->int conversion (and the associated multiply/divide) is hard to say.

Comment: Hot Licks, very interesting, thank you. So it would be like have 3-4 digit floating point precision?

Comment: Hot Licks, but is Float.floatToRawIntBits for c++? could you give me a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you are performing floating point operations along with a conversion from a `float` to `short int` (or vice versa).

In the second case, you have the same floating point operation but there is no conversion. Unless I misunderstand your question, that is why it is faster.

Comment: yes, thank you, type conversion is needed, though I'm not sure that number of convert-function call is big enough, a lot computations with obtained float values is done after conversion.

Comment: Test has shown that this was the reason. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a case of premature optimization. Unless you are storing billions (not just millions) of floating point numbers, the cost of conversion back and forth is going to overwhelm the cost of reading and writing the data. The first approach should always be to simply store those floats in binary format as floats, and only optimize if that I/O turns out to be the bottleneck.

An alternative to using floats is to use a fixed point representation throughout. Languages whose primary purpose is monetary transactions oftentimes provide a built-in fixed point representation. C and C++ are general purpose languages; they don't have this built-in support. However, it isn't that hard to build a fixed point class in C++. Even better, find a fixed point module that someone has already developed if that's the intent.

Comment: thanks for the idea of fixed point representation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it appears you are attempting to optimize an area that is not likely to be a bottleneck.  Second, in doing so, you are decreasing performance for several reasons:

1) The conversion back and forth will cause unnecessary multiplication and division operations.
2) Most modern architectures use 32-bit words, so by attempting to store them in 16-bits you may be introducing alignment problems.

When optimization is necessary, follow [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law):  "Make the common case fast and the rare case correct."

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the question, it appears you are asking why A (described below) takes more time than B (also described below).

A is:

- Upon input, inverse scale data by `k`, convert it from `float` to `short`, and store it in an array.
- To perform calculations, convert data from `short` to `float`, scale it by `k`, and calculate in `float`.

B is:

- Upon input, inverse scale data by `k` and store it in an array.
- To perform calculations, scale it by `k`, and calculate in `float`.

If this is your question, the answer is that A has more operations than B.

It should also be noted that, when the `StoreType` is `float`, the scaling and inverse scaling appear to be pointless.

In theory, reducing the size of data by converting it to `short` could save time because less memory is used, and thus more data fits into cache, and accessing cache is faster than accessing memory. However, for many applications, this will not provide a performance benefit, either because the data is small enough to fit in cache while it is `float` anyway or because the data is large enough that it does not fit in cache even when it is `short` (and/or your data access patterns might be unsuitable for cache for various reasons).

Comment: It is not the same. In case B I call convert functions as well.

Comment: @klm123: You call the convert functions but they do not do anything (`k` is one or omitted)? Or they still multiply and divide by `k` but do not convert from `float` to `short` or vice-versa? In either of those cases, A still has more operations than B.

Comment: The convertion functions are shown. They have multiplication and division. How can they do nothing just because StoreType == float??

Comment: @klm123: I was considering the possibility that `k` were one when `StoreType` was `float`, because it is common to scale when converting to an integer point but for the scale to be unnecessary when staying in a floating-point type. However, even if you are still multiplying and dividing when `StoreType` is `float`, the routines still do fewer operations. When `StoreType` is `short`, the routines multiply or divide and convert. When `StoreType` is `float`, the routines multiply or divide but do not convert. Thus, there is a conversion with `short` that is not present with `float`.

Comment: k is same. type convert would be additional operation, yes, thank you.